# How can I do a Django query with a filter whose left operand is an expression?

Tags: django, django-queryset

The documentation for Django QuerySet API explains how to filter results using field lookups. The problem I have is that this approach requires the left hand operand to be a field and I need it to be an expression, to achieve the equivalent of `(' ' || tagnames || ' ') LIKE '% xyz %'`.

What's the best way to do this? To clarify what I mean by "best": I'm hoping for something that will be independent of the actual database used.

Comment: why do you need this? What is the really issue?

Comment: @danihp The issue is that I'm working on a patch for software that stores a space-separated list of tags in a field, but there's no space at the beginning or the end of the field value (e.g. 'django django-queryset'). I want to check whether a specific tag is present in that list. If I do `tagnames LIKE '%pqr%` it will include rows that have the tag 'opqrs', not just those that have the tag 'pqr'. That's why I want to use the condition I specified above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is the following (not sure if it's necessarily the *best* way):

```
from django.db.models import Q

...filter(Q(tag_name__startswith=tag_value+' ') | Q(tag_name__contains=' '+tag_value+' ') | Q(tag_name__endswith=' '+tag_value))
```

Also, you can always just use the actual SQL you're wanting to use with the `raw` method.

```
SomeModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM my_table')
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with one of those or with `extra`, as suggested by @second. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not sure i follow. do you mean that the field name you are filtering on is decided by an expression? in which case

```
...filter(**{tag_name: tag_value})
```

may be what you are looking for

Comment: No, I know the field name, but I'm not filtering by field, I'm filtering by an expression derived from that field. To illustrate the difference: instead of `X like '%A%'`, I want `(' ' || X || ' ') like '% A %'`

Comment: i see. think you may be stuck with `extra` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Answer (score 0):

For your query  (' ' || tagnames || ' ') LIKE ' %xyz% ' is enought with:

```
...filter( tag_name__contais = tag_value)
```

because blanks can be simplified.

ops! you have changed question!

for your new query (' ' || tagnames || ' ') LIKE '% xyz %':

```
tag_list = tag_value.split(" ")

...filter( tag_name__in = tag_value)
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the change. It's a bit late and it took me a bit before I realized I had a typo in what I wrote :(

Comment: @VojislavStojkovic, ok, here the answer. I ask more explanation to you before question been fixed.